# What are good conventions for Google Analytics on Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I'm about to implement Google Analytics support in an Android app, but after some googling, the documentation seems delightfully sparse. Are there any useful conventions or advice (i.e. when not to trigger pageviews/events, or something) that a newcomer to GA should know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use events to report exceptions in case users are too lazy to hit the 'Report' button.  Also useful for exceptions that you handle internally but want to understand and deal with user error.

An example of the later - I have a numeric EditText (that even has inputType:number) but users still find ways to trigger NumberFormatExceptions that I handle with a default value.  When I saw how many times I handled this case, I realized that I needed to better explain how to use that field.

Comment: This is also a good read for a solid general approach to using the analytics API:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216692/google-analytics-in-android-app-dealing-with-multiple-activities/6253664

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use page views only one per activity.
Then I map and record events on user interaction (button touch, item selection and so on).
Practically the same as a real website.

Answer (score 1):

Related to [Google Analytics in Android app - dealing with multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216692/google-analytics-in-android-app-dealing-with-multiple-activities/6253664#6253664)