# Using AspectJ for adding functionality for superclass method

Tags: java, android, aop, aspectj

I write the Android app, and I want to use custom fonts. So, I decided to use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) for that.

To use this library I need to override base method `attachBaseContext` in every `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
...
}
```

Of course I can use OOP for that, but I want to do it using `AspectJ`.

To incude `AspectJ` in my `gradle` project I use [gradle-android-aspectj-plugin](https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin).

Here is code of my aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("execution(void com.youtubeplaylist.app.ui.activity.*+.attachBaseContext(context))")
    public void beforeCalligraphy(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        Context c = (Context) args[0];
        c = CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(c);
        args[0] = c;
        thisJoinPoint.proceed(args);
        System.out.println("Aspect finished successfully");
    }
}
```

So, **"Aspect finished successfully"** never prints. Please, help me understand what's the problem.

Comment: Did you add ajdt support in the .project file of your project?

Comment: Sorry @Materazzi06, I don't understand what do you mean. I https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin, and I have `gradle` project. I don't have any `*.poject` files.

Comment: Ok I am sorry. I am using AspectJ in eclipse and everything seems to work good even for private and superclass methods. I am not sure for gradle project.

Comment: You may have to go for the call-joinpoint instead of execution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149106/2191746

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373950/612206) on another question :

> When using aspectJ with android you are limited to compile-time weaving, which basically means that you can only intercept code you own.

Compile time weaving will only change the way your own .class behave. If you override the `attachBaseContext` method yourself and leave it empty, and your aspect will work.