# Aspectj how to write pointcut for onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, aspectj

I am using AspectJ for Android and I need to write pointcut execution for onDestroy() even though onDestroy() is not defined in the Activity. Since onDestroy() is always called when app is closed as a part of activity lifecycle irrespective of whether it is defined or not, how do I write pointcut for onDestroy() in case it is not defined in Activity

Comment: what is the pointcut expression that you used?

Comment: I have not used any pointcut expression. I wanted to know what pointcut expression I can use for onDestroy() if it is not defined in Activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AspectJ in Android: pointcut call(\* Activity.onCreate(..)) doesn't pick out Activity.onCreate() calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356375/aspectj-in-android-pointcut-call-activity-oncreate-doesnt-pick-out-acti)