# Android Easy Tracker Fundamentals

Tags: android, google-analytics

I wanted to do analytics on multiple pages and I saw a post saying that you needed to implement the EasyTracker and all it's files. I extended TrackedActivity with my class, but I need clarifying questions as the documentation on this is horrid. (I also added the String UA stuff etc.)

I used this sites to help myself (I understand that the EasyTracker handles when onResume and all other similar functions are called):
[Google Analytics in Android app - dealing with multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216692/google-analytics-in-android-app-dealing-with-multiple-activities/6253664#6253664)

1) I seem to see only examples on ListViews. Is this still applicable with non-ListViews?

2) How does EasyTracker track data? From what I see in the NotePad example it just extends TrackedActivity http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Ftracking%2Fmobile%2Fandroid%2FEasyTracker%2FExamples%2FNotePad

3) How does it track multiple pages as opposed to one?

In other words I'm extremely confused.

Comment: AFAIK Easy tracker only tracks Activities. It does so by giving your a subclassed Activity (TrackedActivity) that sends the tracking event when the Activity is resumed. If you wish to track pageviews within an application you'll have to either make every page its own activity, or forget the EasyTracker and implement the tracking yourself with the "manual" API.

Comment: the easy tracker is used only for activities? what happens when some activities extend from its classes and some don't?